# Google maps image width 960 or printscreen google maps legal?

Tags: image, google-maps, static

Is it possible to get a static Google maps image with a width of 960px? If it's not possible then is it legal to make a printscreen of google maps and put it on my on website as backgroundimage?

Answer (score 2):

The maximum width(with a free license, I guess you don't want to purchase a business-license) as documented is 640.

But you may use the scale-parameter to get a larger image:

[`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Berlin&zoom=13&size=480x300&&sensor=false&scale=2`](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Berlin&zoom=13&size=480x300&&sensor=false&scale=2)

The usage of screenshots is not permitted, the image must be loaded from google.